# Pass a variable from .js file to a php page

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I want to pass a variable from my js file to a php page, I use ajax but don't understand why it doesn't work, here is my code

JS

```
$.ajax({
        url: "result.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: { value: attempts } 
});
```

PHP

```
if (isset($_POST['value'])) {
    echo $_POST['value']; 
}
```

Comment: How do you confirm that "it doesn't work"? What would you expect to happen and what doesn't?

Comment: Quick tip: there is a network inspector in most browsers these days. Use that to observe your request.

Comment: @deceze: I expet it to show my value, but page is still clear

Comment: Then your expectation is wrong. It's being output as part of the AJAX response, but that's not going to just simply appear on the site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have a callback function upon return. The echo $value is sent back to the original AJAX function but you're not handling it.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
$.ajax({ url: "result.php", type: "POST", data: { value: attempts } }).done(function (data) { alert(data); });
```

Comment: I used .done(function(data) {alert(data.value); }); and it alerts undefined  !!!

Comment: That's because your PHP doesn't return an object (JSON). It just returns the value. If you'd use console.log(data); and check your console, you'd see an object that contains "returnMessage" or "data" or anything like that; that contains just your value. 

You can also see that I alerted "data" instead of "data.value". Alerting data will probably result in you seeing [object Object] instead of undefined.


If you want to return an object you will have to create an object in PHP and return it using JSON_encode($object);

Comment: I don't want to use object, I want only to print my value in php page, how to do this?

Comment: thanks, i get my answer

Answer (score 0):

replace your php scripts you need to assign a post value or echo your post value `echo $_POST['value'];`

```
if (isset($_POST['value'])) {
    $value = $_POST['value'];  
    echo $value; 
}
```

Comment: I made a mistake in writing the question, now it is right

Answer (score 0):

Data returned from an AJAX request will not simply appear on your page. First of all, *where* should they appear? *How* should they appear? Often you request complex JSON arrays in your AJAX queries, they can't simply be dumped to the screen as is. You need to explicitly *output the data using Javascript*.

The easiest test is:

```
$.ajax({
    url     : "result.php",
    type    : "POST",
    data    : { value: attempts },
    success : function (data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

In practice you probably don't just want to `alert` the data, but put it into some element using `$('.someElement').text(data)` or something along those lines.